# VBA Insert Multiple Row data based on a listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, copy

For each line of the selected listbox I want to insert data in the next blank row for every data selected in the listbox, one new copied row, but the text that comes from the Textbox must be copied equal in all row, the below code copied the text only in one single row

```
Private sub button1_click()
Dim rw  as integer
Dim ws as worksheets
Set worksheets(“Sheet1”)
Rw = ws.cells.find(what:=“*”, searchorder:=xlrows, searchdirection:=xlprevious, lookin:xlvalues).row + 1
Ws.cells(rw, 3).value = me.textbox1.value
Ws.cells(rw, 5).value = me.listbox1.value
End sub
```

Please help me

Comment: What is your question though? Are you getting an error? And if so, where does it occur? Or is the outcome of your code not as expected? Please update your question to address these items so it's cleared what we are looking at.

Comment: I think that I have explains better the question

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You are saying "For each line of the selected listbox of the listbox" which 1) implies there is a listbox with multi-select enabled - is this the case?, 2) you want to insert a row but your code is writing data to a row (specifically columns C and E) - Do you *actually* mean you want to `Insert a new row` or do you mean you want to write the data to the next blank row? It might be good to add some screenshots of your `userform` and your codes outcome/your expected outcome for clarity.

Comment: Yes I need to write data in the next blank row, but one row for every data selected in listbox

Comment: And is the `ListBox` multiselect? Meaning can a user select more than 1 value in the listbox at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new `Workbook` and a new `UserForm` with a `ListBox`, `TextBox` and `CommandButton` all with default names for this example.

```
Option Explicit
____________________________________________________________________________________

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim NextBlankRow As Long
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim ListBoxItem As Long
Dim SelectedItemsArray As Variant
Dim ArrayElementCounter As Long

ArrayElementCounter = 0

With Me.ListBox1
ReDim SelectedItemsArray(0 To .ListCount - 1)
    For ListBoxItem = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(ListBoxItem) Then
            SelectedItemsArray(ArrayElementCounter) = .List(ListBoxItem)
            ArrayElementCounter = ArrayElementCounter + 1
        End If
    Next ListBoxItem
End With

ReDim Preserve SelectedItemsArray(0 To ArrayElementCounter - 1)

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    NextBlankRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set TargetRange = .Range("C" & NextBlankRow & ":C" & NextBlankRow + UBound(SelectedItemsArray))
End With

Dim TargetCell As Range

ArrayElementCounter = 0
For Each TargetCell In TargetRange
    TargetCell.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    TargetCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = SelectedItemsArray(ArrayElementCounter)
    ArrayElementCounter = ArrayElementCounter + 1
Next TargetCell

End Sub

____________________________________________________________________________________

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ListBoxItemArray As Variant

ListBoxItemArray = Array("Listbox Item 1", "Listbox Item 2", "Listbox Item 3")

Dim ItemToAdd As Long

For ItemToAdd = LBound(ListBoxItemArray) To UBound(ListBoxItemArray)
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem (ListBoxItemArray(ItemToAdd))
Next ItemToAdd

End Sub
```

Here are screenshots of the inputs and outputs:

**Data selected/entered to the `UserForm`**

[[image: Screenshot of UserForm with selected listbox items and textbox text[1]]

**Output to the worksheet**

[image: Screenshot of output to the worksheet]

---

### Explanation:

The `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` event populates the `ListBox` for the purposes of my example - You can ignore this when it comes to your code but I felt it necessary to include how I populated the `ListBox Items` and what values with.

The `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` event code breaks down into 4 main sections (starting after the variables are declared):

1. `With Me.LisBox1...End With`

The very first thing we do here is set the Array size with the [`ReDim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) statement. The `UpperBound` or limit of the Array is set to the `ListCount` property minus 1 which returns 1 less the number of items in the `ListBox`. This ensures our Array is big enough to hold all of the list box items values, if they were all selected for example, but does so dynamically so you don't waste memory using an ambiguous number to future proof your code like `100` when you might only have 30 items. If Items are added or removed, the Array is *always* the right size.

The reason we minus 1 is I declared the `Option Base` to `0` for the Array which means it starts at (or the `Lower Bound` is) 0 not at 1. See the [Option Base Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement) for more info.

Next we loop through each `ListBox` item and evaluate if it is `Selected` or not. If it is, we use the `List()` property to assign the value of that item to the Array. See [For...Next loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) for more info on how they work and see [Using Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays) for how they work.

Now we have `SelectedItemsArray()` full of the values for each selected item in the listbox.

2. `ReDim Preserve SelectedItemsArray(0 To ArrayElementCounter - 1)`

Much like earlier, we are setting the size of our array but this time including the `Preserve` part of the statement. This means we can resize the array but keep all the current values in it - If we didn't use `Preserve` the Array would be resized but lose all values. We again set the `Upper Bound` dynamically to resize the array to the number of selected items. (See the [Using Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays) info again regarding array sizes etc.)

3. `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")...End With`

In this `With` block we are finding the last used row of `Column C` and assigning that row + 1 (so it references the next blank row) to `LastUsedRow`. We are also defining our range we want to write our data to dynamically using the `LastUsedRow` variable and the `Upper Bound` of our Array. This is done so the right amount of cells are written to in the next section of code.

4. `For Each TargetCell In TargetRange...Next TargetCell`

Another loop but this time [`For Each...Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) is used. Very similar to the `For...Next` loop but this one loops through elements of an array or collection - in this case we will be looping through each cell in our `TargetRange`.

For each cell in the range, remembering our range is set to `Column C` from the next blank row, The `TextBox` value is written to Column C and each `ListBox` item value from our array is written to Column E. As the loop iterates, the `ArrayItemCounter` increments which ensures the next array element is written to Column E with each loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just last question, how can I add another TextBox? Just copy and paste the code textbox1? Or I need to change the array?

Comment: Copy/paste for another textbox should be fine. The array is to gather the listbox items only and write them to the sheet correctly.